# When is it guaranteed that images' dimensions within ng-repeat are available in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="entriesCtrl">
  <img ng-repeat="entry in entries"
       ng-src="{{entry.url}}" id="{{entry.id}}"/>
</div>
```

And I try to get the images' sizes from the DOM, after populating the model:

```
angular.module('foobar', [])
    .controller('entriesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/entries.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.entries = data;
        };
        $scope.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            entry.height = angular.element('#'+entry.id).height();
        };
    });
```

But with the code as-is, I get `undefined` values for all heights. It works if I do the following ugly hack:

```
angular.module('foobar', [])
    .controller('entriesCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $http.get('/entries.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.entries = data;
        };
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                entry.height = angular.element('#'+entry.id).height();
            };
        }, 500);
    });
```

If ever the browser lags and takes more than my arbitrary 500ms to get the data into the DOM, my code will fail. Is there some way to execute my forEach when it is guaranteed to get the calculated heights?

I tried to put it in a `ng-init` in an element after the `img` but I got `undefined` there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to accomplish your requirement is:

```
.directive('getHeight', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
         element.on('load', function() {
             scope.entry.height = element.height();
         }
    };
}

<div ng-controller="entriesCtrl">
  <img ng-repeat="entry in entries"
       ng-src="{{entry.url}}" get-height/>
</div>
```

As an answer to the question:

> Is there some way to execute my forEach when it is guaranteed to get
>   the calculated heights?

There is no way to do this (the guarantee).  Your code is using an angular anti-pattern - manipulating the DOM outside of a directive.  The reason this is unsafe is that angular can modify the DOM at any time, and any assumptions about it's structure cannot be guaranteed.

The only safe place to manipulate the DOM in angular is inside of a directive, and even then you must be careful about the assumptions you make.  For instance, with images, without using the load event, there is no way to know for sure that the image loaded successfully.

Comment: And then there's the fact that if the image is cached, the load event may not even be called unless you bind it before setting the src.

Comment: The irony is that I had in my reading list [Best Practice - Dom Manipulations](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/), but it starts with "*Lets talk about best practices and roles in AngularJS*", so my first cursory reading had me get from it that it's best to restrict DOM manipulations to directives.

Now I have an example that some DOM manipulations actually can't work reliably outside directives… (to be fair, in my experience, that's almost always the case with best practices, it's just a question of how soon you get the case where only the best practice works reliably)